# Which values for Netem to emulate WAN?

Tags: ubuntu, latency, wide-area-network, tc, jitter

I am developing a distributed application, which I'm currently running on a cluster of Ubuntu VMs over LAN. I'd like to evaluate the performance of my application over WAN. So I decided to use [Netem and tc](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) to add network delay, etc. . My problem is that I don't know which values to set for latency, jitter, packet loss, etc. which represents a generalized WAN for creating meaningful evaluation results that supports my claim that the application has been evaluated over WAN? I've not found so far a resource indicating that, forwarding me to such a resource would be also very welcomed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WANs can be very different. It can be a stable link to the next city or it can be a satellite link to the other side of the globe. Just get cloud VMs in different regions and measure link characteristics between them yourself.